# Creating a generic method in C# through specific where clause

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-collections, generic-constraints

I want to create some generic methods like code below:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url) where T : IBaseModel, IList<IBaseModel>
```

Obviously I want to support enumerable collection and also the single object which drived from `IBaseModel` interface.
The method definition is OK, but when it comes to its usage I'll get following error:

```
await myClass.Get<List<DrivedClassFromBaseModel>>("some url");

There is no implicit conversion from "System.Collection.Generic.List<DrivedClassFromBaseModel> to System.Collection.Generic.IList<IBaseModel>"
```

Comment: You cannot cast a list of a derived type to a list with the base class. That would allow for other types with the same base class to be added to that list.

Comment: How `List<DrivedClassFromBaseModel>` could be `IBaseModel` ?

Comment: You should be able to do Task<List<T>> Get<T>(string url) where T : IBaseModel

Comment: @Reza Aghaei DrivedClassFromBaseModel:IBaseModel

Comment: I see, but `DrivedClassFromBaseModel:IBaseModel` doesn't mean `List<DrivedClassFromBaseModel>` is `IBaseModel`. As it's already mentioned in the answer, `where T : IBaseModel, IList<IBaseModel>` means `T` should implement both `IBaseModel` and `IList<IBaseModel>`.

Answer (score 5):

[Generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) will be combined by AND, so `where T : IBaseModel, IList<IBaseModel>` means `T` should implement both `IBaseModel` and `IList<IBaseModel>`.

You need to create two methods:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url) where T : IBaseModel
public async Task<IList<T>> GetList<T>(string url) where T : IBaseModel
```

Comment: If these two methods are member of the same class which can have `<T>` as common generic constraint, move `T` to generic parameters of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another class which implements both IBaseModel and IList, and then T is constrained to this class.

```
public class DerivedModel : IBaseModel, IList<IBaseModel>
{
    private int _size;
    private IBaseModel[] _items=new IBaseModel[1000];
    private int _version;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<IBaseModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
...
}
```

And the generic method is:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url) where T : DerivedModel 
    {
        return await Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var derivedModel = new DerivedModel() {new BaseModel() {Id = 1}};
            return (T) derivedModel;
        });
    }
```

In which the IBaseModel and BaseModel can be:

```
public interface IBaseModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel : IBaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The usage:

```
var inheritance=new Inheritance();
var result = await inheritance.Get<DerivedModel>("aaa");
textBox1.Text = result[0].Id.ToString();
```